# Process.start being used to launch browser but is now deprecated

Tags: f#, f#-fake, saturn-framework

If I go through the "How to start" guide for Saturn:

https://saturnframework.org/tutorials/how-to-start.html

when I run the last step:

```
dotnet fake build -t run
```

the webserver does indeed appear to start. I can go to http://localhost:8085/books and see the resulting application.

However, if I ctrl-c at the console to stop the webserver, I notice the following:

[image]

If I look at `build.fsx`, it contains the following line:

```
Process.start (fun i -> { i with FileName = "http://localhost:8085" }) |> ignore
```

within the `Run` target:

```ml
Target.create "Run" (fun _ ->
  let server = async {
    DotNet.exec (fun p -> { p with WorkingDirectory = appPath } ) "watch" "run" |> ignore
  }
  let browser = async {
    Thread.Sleep 5000
    Process.start (fun i -> { i with FileName = "http://localhost:8085" }) |> ignore
  }

  [ server; browser]
  |> Async.Parallel
  |> Async.RunSynchronously
  |> ignore
)
```

So it looks like the intention of the `Run` target is to start a browser for us.

The warning in the output above indicates:

```
Warning FS0044: This construct is deprecated. use the CreateProcess APIs instead.
```

The [Just start a process](https://fake.build/core-process.html) page in the Fake documentation has some examples. Going off those, I used the changed `build.fsx` to use the following line:

```
CreateProcess.fromRawCommand "cmd.exe" [ "/C"; "start http://localhost:8085" ] |> Proc.run |> ignore
```

And that does indeed seem to work.

Couple of questions:

- Is that the recommended way to achieve something like this?
- The above can only be expected to work on Windows. Is there a cross-platform way to open a URL with a browser using Fake?

## Note

If you decide to go through the Saturn "How to start" guide, I recommend that you remove the file `global.json` after step 3. The default one currently looks for a particular version of .NET SDK. There is a [pull-request](https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn.Template/pull/31) open to resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: What gives you the idea that it's Windows-only?

Comment: Hey @FyodorSoikin. I'm referring to the `cmd.exe` in the new line that I used to replace the older deprecated approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the Plotly.NET source for a way to start a browser: https://github.com/plotly/Plotly.NET/blob/62f297649320783ea0e64725ff4703bb225268d0/src/Plotly.NET/ChartExtensions.fs#L16

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and reference, nh2!

Comment: I've made a pull request based on your suggestion:

https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn.Template/pull/32